# When JSF including a page, it's not working but with direct values in include is working

Tags: jsf, uiinclude

While doing  in the JSF page, its save functionality is working but while doing `<ui:include src="#{initilizingBean.displaypageurl}"/>`, the page is getting included but the save functionality is not working of the included page.

Any help is welcome.please help me out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition template="/templates/subTemplate.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:omni="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/omni/tags">


    <head>
<title>Form Tabs</title>
    </head>

    <body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
        <a4j:status>
            <f:facet name="start">
                <h:graphicImage value="/images/ai.gif" />
            </f:facet>
        </a4j:status>
        <ui:define name="content_body">
            <div class="uiContainer100">
                <omni:errormessage id="globalMessages" />
                <table class="grid">
                    <tr>
                        <th width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{msg['remrkDet.appNo']}" /></th>
                        <td width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{userSessionData.applicationNo}">

                            </h:outputText></td>


                        <th width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{msg['employmentDetail.facilityCode']}" /></th>
                        <td width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{userSessionData.productDesc}" /></td>


                        <th width="12.5%"><h:outputText value="#{msg['cr.applied']}" />
                        </th>
                        <td width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{userSessionData.appliedAmount}"
                                style="text-align: right">
                                <f:convertNumber pattern="##,###,###,##0.00"
                                    maxFractionDigits="2" />
                            </h:outputText> <h:outputText value=" ( #{userSessionData.currencyCode} )" /></td>
                        <th width="12.5%"><h:outputText value="Approved Amount" /></th>
                        <td width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{userSessionData.approvedAmount}"
                                style="text-align: right">
                                <f:convertNumber pattern="##,###,###,##0.00"
                                    maxFractionDigits="2" />
                            </h:outputText> <h:outputText value=" ( #{userSessionData.currencyCode} )" /></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <th width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{msg['bnkguaran.appnme']}" /></th>
                        <td width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{userSessionData.applicantName}" /></td>
                        <th width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{msg['genrWrkFlw.subFacCd']}" /></th>
                        <td width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{userSessionData.subFacilityDesc}" /></td>

                        <th width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{msg['genrWrkFlw..appten']}" /></th>
                        <td width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{userSessionData.appledTenure}" /> <h:outputText
                                value=" ( In months)" /></td>

                        <th width="12.5%"><h:outputText value="Approved Tenure" /></th>
                        <td width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{userSessionData.approvedTenure}" /> <h:outputText
                                value=" ( In months)" /></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>

                        <th width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{msg['retailApplication.procStat']}" /></th>
                        <td width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{userSessionData.taskName}" /></td>

                        <th width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{msg['genrWrkFlw.appBrnch']}" /></th>
                        <td width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{userSessionData.applicationBranchName}" /></td>

                        <th width="12.5%"><h:outputText value="ROI" /></th>
                        <td width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{userSessionData.interestRate}"
                                style="text-align: right">
                                <f:convertNumber pattern="##,###,###,##0.00"
                                    maxFractionDigits="2" />
                            </h:outputText></td>

                        <th width="12.5%"><h:outputText value="Approved ROI" /></th>
                        <td width="12.5%"><h:outputText
                                value="#{userSessionData.approvdRateOfInterest}"
                                style="text-align: right">
                                <f:convertNumber pattern="##,###,###,##0.00"
                                    maxFractionDigits="2" />
                            </h:outputText></td>
                    </tr>


                </table>

            </div>

            <!--  new code start -->
            <div class="uiContainer100">

                    <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">

                            <h:form>

                            <rich:panelMenu style="width:150px" 
                                    itemMode="ajax" groupMode="ajax"
                                    groupExpandedLeftIcon="triangleUp"
                                    groupCollapsedLeftIcon="triangleDown"
                                    topGroupExpandedRightIcon="chevronUp"
                                    topGroupCollapsedRightIcon="chevronDown" itemLeftIcon="disc" >

                                    <c:forEach
                                        items="#{initializeFormTabsBean.parentMapList.entrySet()}"
                                        var="entry">
                                        <br> <h:commandLink
                                                action="#{initializeFormTabsBean.onParentGroupTabClick()}" value="#{entry.key}">
                                                <f:param name="testForm" value="#{entry.key}" />
                                            </h:commandLink> 
                                     </br>      
                                    </c:forEach>

                                </rich:panelMenu>




                        </h:form>

                            </td>
                        <td>
                                <c:if
                                    test="#{initializeFormTabsBean.parentMapList!=null and initializeFormTabsBean.parentMapList.size()>0}"> 

                                    <c:forEach
                                        items="#{initializeFormTabsBean.parentMapList.entrySet()}"
                                        var="entry">

                                    </c:forEach>
                        <rich:tabPanel switchType="client" 
                                                activeItem="#{dynamicPanelBean.activeTab}">
                                                <rich:tab header="#{initializeFormTabsBean.displayPageTabHeader}" status="status" 
                                                        name="#{initializeFormTabsBean.displayPageTabName}"
                                                        onheaderclick="#{initializeFormTabsBean.displayPageTabName}('#{initializeFormTabsBean.displayPageTabHeader}')">
                                                        <ui:include src="#{initializeFormTabsBean.displayPageUrl}"></ui:include>
                                                    </rich:tab> 

                                    </rich:tabPanel>        </c:if> 

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
            </div>




            <br></br>
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="content_right_panel">
            <ui:include src="/omni/los/dashboard/appRightPanelTemplate.xhtml"></ui:include>
        </ui:define>
    </body>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: please share your code, we would be able to help you better.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And check http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and [ask]